# Reading double from CSV file

Tags: java, csv, parsing, save

I am trying to write a program that calculates the odds/ cost of winning the lottery. The previous total spent and number of runs are saved to a csv file as a double and int respectively. When I write a number into the file by hand for the total spent(w/o a decimal) it runs fine, but as soon as the number is saved I cant run it again. I believe the issue related to the formatting used for larger numbers and/or the use of parseInt, but I am not certain. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
public class WinningTheLottery
{
public static final int SIZE = 5;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] winningNums = new int[SIZE];
    int[] guessNums = new int[SIZE];
    int spent, runs = 1, oldRuns = 0, totalSpent = 0, bothRuns = 0;
    double oldTotal = 0.0, newAvg, bothTotal = 0.0;
    String line;
    String[] parts;
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    try
    {
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("average.csv"));
        while (fileScanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            line = fileScanner.nextLine();
            parts = line.split(",");
            oldTotal = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            oldRuns = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
        {
            spent = 0;
            randomlyAssignedNumbers(winningNums);
            // Arrays.toString(nameOfArray) => built in method to print an array
            System.out.println("\n[" + (i+1) + "] Todays winning numbers:\n" + Arrays.toString(winningNums).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
            do
            {
                randomlyAssignedNumbers(guessNums);
                spent++;
            } while (howManyCorrect(winningNums, guessNums) < 5);
            System.out.println("After spending " + currency.format(spent) + ", you won the Fantasy 5 lottery $75,000 prize!");
            totalSpent += spent;
        }
        bothTotal = totalSpent + oldTotal;
        bothRuns = runs + oldRuns;
        newAvg = (bothTotal/bothRuns);
        PrintWriter fileWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("average.csv"));
        fileWriter.println(bothTotal + "," + bothRuns);
        System.out.println("\nAverage Cost to win the Lottery: " + currency.format(newAvg));
        fileScanner.close();
        fileWriter.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

public static void randomlyAssignedNumbers(int[] anyArray)
{
    Random rng = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < anyArray.length; i++)
    {
        anyArray[i] = rng.nextInt(36) + 1;
    }
}

public static int howManyCorrect(int[] a1, int[] a2)
{
    if (a1.length != a2.length)
        return -1;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++)
    {
        if (a1[i] == a2[i])
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
}
```

Comment: **Integer.parseInt()** doesn't like the decimal point or any alpha character for that matter. The parseInt() method will throw a **NumberFormatException** if a alpha character is encountered (even a space). If the number in file is a string representation of a double data type number then use the **Double.parseDouble()** method to convert that number into a double data type variable.

Comment: A view of the data file contents (or part of it) could be beneficial here.

Comment: when the file contents are :  40000000,2 it works
But when they updated to :   1.44845504E8,4 it throws a NumberFormatException

Comment: Thank you! Parsing as a Double solved it.